# Query Object in Microsoft Azure Mobile Services

Tags: sql, azure, object, mobile

If i want user list of specified user then i can use this.

```
  tblTest.where({ userId: user.userId})
        .read({ success: function(results) { 
           console.log("results",results
     }});
```

But what i want to do is, I want to fetch all user data whose created date is greater than today's date only .
var todayDate = new Date();
How can i use similary code here using query object.

```
select * from tblTest where startDate <= todayDate 

tblTest.where({ startDate <= user.userId})
```

//this doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

```
tblTest.where(function(){
   return startDate <= todayDate;
})
.read({ success: function(results) { 
    console.log("results",results
}});
```

Finally found it. :)